# Alternative for Kies

Tags: samsung-kies, odin

New firmware upgrade is available. I tried to install it through Kies at least 15 times. But every time, it fails. I am using latest version of Kies on my PC.

I Googled for alternative. I found **ODIN** for the same. But I am doubtful whether it is reliable.

Please tell me if someone knows reliable way to upgrade firmware without using Kies.

Comment: Did you try rebooting your device or connecting it while in Download Mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no alternative for Kies.

Kies is the **only** offical way to update Samsung's Android devices.

To unofficially flash/update Samsung devices **Odin (for Windows)** and **[Heimdall](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=755265) (for Linux)** are the de facto standard. These two a very reliable.

Comment: I tried ODIN. and now i am having updated firmware on 1st attempt. But lost my all contacts, data, sms due to my one foolish step.